# SQL Server 2005 date format with day name Monday, May 5th 2014 (without time)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What format string will do this?

```
Monday, May 5th 2014
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

I've looked at various combinations of `CONVERT`.

FORMAT only works in 2008

Comment: `FORMAT` actually is a new function in SQL Server **2012**

Comment: can you used **CONVERT**, but not sure that have that format: [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Convert has a "secret option".  Convert(Varchar(20), mydate, 103).  See Convert formats for a lot of other options.

See: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but somewhat close...

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
SET  @Date = GETDATE();

SELECT  DATENAME(DW,@Date) + ', ' 
        + DATENAME(MONTH, @Date) 
        + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Date, 107), 9)

RESULT: Monday, May 05, 2014
```

Another Option:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(DW,@Date) + ', ' 
       +DATENAME(MONTH, @Date)  + ' '
       + CAST(DAY(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
       + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(@Date) AS NVARCHAR(4))

RESULT: Monday, May 5 2014
```